# Current data on django containers get cleared after rebuilding a Container

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I dockerized my Django application, but every time and make an update and rebuild images, all the data gets cleaned.

Below are the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files:

Docker

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.10-buster as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql gcc python3-dev libpq-dev musl-dev python3-setuptools binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin

# lint
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install flake8
COPY . .
# RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.10-buster

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
# RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
RUN useradd app && usermod -aG app app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install libpq-dev binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin -y
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g'  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x  $APP_HOME/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    # container_name: sph-web
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 5000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    # container_name: sph-db
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

I am having a hard time figuring this out. Kindly assist.

I run the following commands:

`docker-compose down`
and then:

`docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: When you say "all the data gets cleaned", where is it physically stored?

Comment: What commands do you run to stop/delete your running services and rebuild? Are you passing `-v` to `docker compose down`?

Comment: I run the following commands:

`docker-compose down`
 and then:

`docker-compose up -d --build`

Answer (score 0):

Pulling the image (`FROM python:3.8.10-buster`) twice might be causing the issue

---

Edit:

Others think so too: https://www.facebook.com/groups/DevCNairobi/permalink/5039369276127165/